# GSAP Javascript if else statement woes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I'm building a basic online banking app with HTML, CSS, and JS.

So far I have the recent transaction screen and a simple animation for opening each individual transaction's description.

I used GSAP to create the animation, and jQuery for handling elements.

**However, I have run into a problem getting the description window to close after it has been opened.**

[CODEPEN HERE](http://codepen.io/tnormington/pen/QbOPmX), and here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.list li').click(function() {

    var i = $(this).find('i');
    var li = $(this);
    var desc = $(this).next();
    var tl = new TimelineMax({paused:false});
    var open = false;

    if (open === true) {
      tl.to(i, .3, {rotation: 0})
        .to(li, .3, {borderBottom: 'none', delay: -.2})
        .to(desc, .3, {height: '0', padding: '0', delay: -.2});
      open = false;
    } else {
      tl.to(i, .3, {rotation: 90})
        .to(li, .3, {borderBottom: '2px solid #95a5a6', delay: -.2})
        .to(desc, .3, {height: '55px', padding: '5px', delay: -.2});
      open = true;
    }


  });


});
```

I use an if statement to decide which animation to play depending on if the description window is open or closed.

I am a designer learning to code, I will take any advice I can get.

Comment: I just would like to suggest one thing: I think you do not need to create a new **`TimelineMax({...});`** instance every time the user clicks one of your list items.

Comment: Based on my experience (I could be wrong) the idea of **`TimelineMax`** is to just define it once in the script (in your case, once for every list item) and then only adjust the play-head to move *forward* or *backward*. Think of it as a video with a scrub handle, you create it once and then you would only *play*, *pause*, *reverse* etc.

Comment: In fact, in this particular case, I think using **`TweenMax`** may also suffice.

Comment: Also, the way you are using `delay` is a little weird as well. There is a [position parameter](http://greensock.com/position-parameter) available in **`TimelineMax`**, which is what I think you would find useful in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Would I just need to move the TimelineMax variable outside the click handler?

Comment: The easiest and quickest but it still considered a proper solution from my view would be to replace these **`TimelineMax`** calls with **`TweenMax`** calls. Would you like to see a demo of both the approaches that I am proposing? I will find some free time and create them for you if you are interested.

Comment: That would be real cool if you did, this stuff can be confusing >.<

Comment: here is what I propose: http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/km06gofL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but `var open = false;` is in the wrong scope. The way it's written, `open` is defined as `false` every time the click handler is called, You want to put it in the parent scope: outside the click handler, before the click handler is ever called.

**EDIT** since you want to track the "open" state of each element, you need to create a *closure* for each element. You can do that using `.each()`.

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.list li').each(function() {

     var open = false;  // <-- Put "open" here

     $(this).click(function() {

        var i = $(this).find('i');
        var li = $(this);
        var desc = $(this).next();
        var tl = new TimelineMax({paused:false});
        // get rid of "open" here

       if (open === true) {
          tl.to(i, .3, {rotation: 0})
            .to(li, .3, {borderBottom: 'none', delay: -.2})
            .to(desc, .3, {height: '0', padding: '0', delay: -.2});
           open = false;
        } else {
           tl.to(i, .3, {rotation: 90})
             .to(li, .3, {borderBottom: '2px solid #95a5a6', delay: -.2})
             .to(desc, .3, {height: '55px', padding: '5px', delay: -.2});
           open = true;
        }


      });


    });
});
```

Comment: Ah that works! But now if one transaction is opened and you click on a closed transaction, it seems to run through the function once to reset the variable (and maybe apply the closing animation to a closed window?)

Is there an easy fix to this?

Comment: See my modified answer.